# Exception handling in open source code (try-catch)

Tags: design-patterns, exception, try-catch

Finally, I am planning to write open source projects but I am deeply confused. I know that it is a good idea to use exception handling mechanisms in my code but most of the open source projects I see (even the popular ones) don't use try...catch and exceptions. Why? What bad thing would happen if I use them, in open source code?

Comment: What alternative do these open-source projects use in place of try/catch?

Comment: @jaco0646 they simply return values in order to flag errors

Comment: @Fresher what is the language you are referring?? Exception-handling strategies are pretty much language oriented. Ex: Java community pretty much believes in checked exceptions, where .net people believes it as an anti-pattern. If you refer a most scripting-languages things are much different.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne PHP

Comment: @Fresher could you pls link any open source php project you found that doesn't use try-catch at all??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne This is one of them https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth

Comment: @Fresher I see one here https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth#captcha-implementation

Comment: @SupunWijerathne The author is suggesting the user to use that code and does not implement it in the original script. Have a look, the `Auth.php` file has that method named `checkCaptcha()` that simply returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

> but most of the open source projects I see (even the popular ones) don't use try...catch and exceptions.

The base language that you use to develop your framework will greatly influence your strategy on how your framework can or should handle erroneous conditions. Different programming languages have different mechanisms for exception handling. 
Java for example has the concept of *checked* exceptions that the developer is forced to either handle or propagate to the caller. C# on the other hand does not have the concept of *checked* exceptions. Chances are that the frameworks you are referring to use languages that themselves don't have the concept of *checked* exceptions.

Let's take an example. Say you want to build a framework for reading delimited files and loading them into memory (objects). You write a layer that is responsible for reading a file based on the file name and path provided by a programmer. One exceptional condition that will be pretty common in such a framework is that the name of the file or path is invalid. If you built your framework in Java, chances are that you used one of the file reading API's provided by Java to read the file. Most file reading API's in java  `throw` checked exceptions (`FileNotFoundException` for example) which the developer has to handle or propagate. If your language of choice itself forces you to work with exceptions, you are bound to come across a sitation where you are left with no choice but to use the exception framework provided by the language.

> Why? What bad thing would happen if I use them, in open source code?

The real problem with exceptional handling lies in the correct usage of this feature (specially in languages that have the concept of checked exceptions). Inexperienced or lazy programmers may simply abuse this feature by making the exception *pass-through* all the way to the starting point of the application; only to let the runtime envrionment handle the exception. The following code snippet demonstrates one such abuse :

```
public static String loadData(String fileName)throws FileNotFoundException {
    String resource = ResourceManager.getResource(fileName);
    //code to read the file
}

public static boolean containsText(String fileName,String text)throws FileNotFoundException {
    String contents = loadData(fileName);
    if(contents.contains(text)) {
       return truel
    }
    return false;
 }

 public static void main(String []args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    containsText("/home/abc.txt","Account Number");
 }
```

Another way to abuse this feature would be to build an API that has too many checked exceptions being thrown around. This would require users of the API to write more exception handling code than actual business/application logic.